# I cant send mails from my code using Godaddy Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, system.net.sockets

I have been working with Godaddy Email on my website for last 3 years without any problem.
Last week my Godaddy Email that i use in my site to activate accounts was deleted without reason.
So i created again, same account and password, but right now it´s not working anymore. I didn´t modify the class. its the same.
I use Godaddy Workspace and Shared Hosting(Windows).
I get this error:

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder 72.167.234.197:25

English Translate:
Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An error has ocurred during the connection attempt since there was no response after a while, or there was a problem with the established connection and the host hasn't been able to send a response 72.167.234.197:25

```
using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("admin@mydomain.com ", "user@hotmail.com"))
    {
        mm.Subject = "Activation Account";
        string body = "Welcome ";
        mm.Body = body;
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("admin@mydomain.com", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailPassword"]);
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 25;
        smtp.Send(mm);
    }
```

Can anyone help me, i call to Godaddy technical assistance, but they don´t know how to fix it. They just told me i need to use phpmail? So i don´t trust that they can help me.

Comment: Didn't they tell you whether any terms/conditions changed? It seems that host doesn't work anymore

Comment: from https://pl.godaddy.com/help/what-is-my-servers-email-relay-server-16601 it says dedrelay.secureserver.net (its amazing what a short google will give you)

Comment: Double check that they haven't changed any settings like hostname.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I talked with latam Godaddy, they didnt understand what im talking about. A guy from support who tell u that u need to use phpmail is not understanding that u work with .net.

Comment: Just for the record, loosely translated error: "Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An error has ocurred during the connection attempt since there was no response after a while, or there was a problem with the established connection and the host hasn't been able to send a response 72.167.234.197:25"

Comment: @BugFinder I use Shared Hosting, i tried your amazing suggestion, but i get this error: Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: p3plsmtps2ded02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net : HOSTING RELAY : yfxiei1Pctm4D : DED : ESMTP No Relay Quota information retrieved. Please try again.

Comment: @NicolásMarzano Thats right, i didnt touch the VS message. But translation is correct. Thanks.

Comment: `i call to Godaddy technical assistance, but they don´t know how to fix it` Will be amazing if they do. Once I asked them why my asp.net mvc site failed to load. Support: where are your .aspx pages? Me: they are precompiled. Support: How is it possible? you are doing it wrong. Im not seeing those .aspx files thus your site doesn't work.

Comment: it will depend a lot on what service you have with godaddy - but it does sound like they put some of their finest on support (with huge sarcasm in case someone missed it) im guessing that when they remade you they may not have done all of it, or you have a slightly different service because they changed it.. etc